# Laravel image cache using Dropbox as disk

Tags: laravel, image, caching, dropbox

I'm using this package (https://github.com/spatie/flysystem-dropbox) to storage and get images from Dropbox.

This works fine but images have to load everytime the page is refreshed. I wonder if you know any image cache solution that works in this case and if can please provide with a minimal working example.

Thanks.

Comment: You could create your own rudimentary caching system by using a route to serve the images. Requests to the route would get routed to a controller where you check the local file system to see if the file exists. If it doesn't exist get it from Dropbox, save it to the local file system, and serve it. If it already exists in the local file system just serve it from the local file system.

Comment: @Jeemusu Thanks, add this comment as an answer please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this would be to create your own caching system. If the image doesn't exist on your local file system, pull it from Dropbox and then save it to the local file system and serve it. If it already exists in the local file system just serve it from the local file system.

## 1 Route

Serve the images from their own route.

```
Route::get('images/{filename}', [
    'uses'    => 'ImageController@getImage'
]);
```

## 2 Controller

Check the local file system to see if the file already exists, otherwise pull it from dropbox and store it in the local file system.

```
<?php 

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class ImageController extends Controller 

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function getImage($filename)
    {
        // If the file doesn't exist
        if(!file_exists('/path/to/' . $filename)) {

            // 1. Get the image from dropbox

            // 2. Save the image to local storage
        }

        // 3. Serve the image from local storage
    }
}
```